# Determine TLS version in wireshark

Tags: ssl, https, tls1.2, wireshark, tls1.3

I am confused about which TLS version is used, when inspecting packets in Wireshark.
In the Client Hello package it says "TLSv1.3 Record Layer", the version beneath says "TLS 1.0" and for the Handshake Protocol it says "Version: TLS 1.2".

[image: Wireshark capture]

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. But in short you are seeing TLS 1.3, Wireshark is right. To ensure smooth transitions, it kept using old version numbers in TLS records themselves. See for example this line in RFC 8446: "In
      TLS 1.3, the client indicates its version preferences in the
      "supported_versions" extension (Section 4.2.1) and the
      legacy_version field MUST be set to 0x0303, which is the version
      number for TLS 1.2.".

Comment: And also earlier in same document (a needed reading if you want to fully master TLS 1.3): "In order to maximize backward
   compatibility, a record containing an initial ClientHello SHOULD have
   version 0x0301 (reflecting TLS 1.0) and a record containing a second
   ClientHello or a ServerHello MUST have version 0x0303 (reflecting
   TLS 1.2)."

Answer (score 1):

Because RFC 8446 descirbed:

```
struct {
   ProtocolVersion legacy_version = 0x0303;    /* TLS v1.2 */
   Random random;
   opaque legacy_session_id<0..32>;
   CipherSuite cipher_suites<2..2^16-2>;
   opaque legacy_compression_methods<1..2^8-1>;
   Extension extensions<8..2^16-1>;
} ClientHello;
```

The client must use 0x0303 (TLS 1.2) to make TLS 1.3 handshake successfully when some interval server did not implement TLS version negotiation correctly.

Instead, we use `supported_versions` in the Extension to tell the server that the client can support the TLS 1.3:

[image]